# Is it possible to use scalar valued functions with LINQ to SQL?

Tags: sql-server

I can't use any design surface, it causes all kinds of issues, so I have to manually edit the dbml file myself.

I've put this in the dbml:

```
  <Function Name="dbo.Func_IsDisplayed" Method="Func_IsDisplayed">
    <Parameter Name="EmployeeID" Parameter="employeeID" Type="System.Int32" DbType="Int" />
    <Parameter Name="FiscalYear" Parameter="fiscalYear" Type="System.Int32" DbType="Int" />
    <Return Type="System.Boolean" />
  </Function>
```

For SPs this always works fine. The calling line of code is:

```
isDisplayed = db.Func_IsDisplayed(employeeID, fiscalYear);
```

But at runtime it results in the following exception:
'System.Boolean' is not a valid return type for a mapped stored procedure method.

The return type for the function in SQL Server is `BIT`.

What do I need to change in the DBML? Do I need to specify that it's a scalar valued function somehow?

Comment: I am guessing, but try  <Return Type="System.Int32">,  BIT normally maps to integer not boolean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the `IsComposable` property and set it to `true`. This also allows other return types besides `Int32`.

```
  <Function Name="dbo.Func_IsDisplayed" Method="Func_IsDisplayed" IsComposable="true">
    <Parameter Name="EmployeeID" Parameter="employeeID" Type="System.Int32" DbType="Int" />
    <Parameter Name="FiscalYear" Parameter="fiscalYear" Type="System.Int32" DbType="Int" />
    <Return Type="System.Boolean" />
  </Function>
```